# dnf update not working in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, repository, dnf

Unable to run `dnf update` command as root in CentOS8. Below error occurred while,

```
Failed to open log file: /var/log/hawkey.log
```

Comment: As *roaima* already pointed out - do you run this command as root? If not, you can use `sudo dnf update`, if you have sudo access. If you don't have sudo access, login as root `su - root` then run your dnf command. If you already run this command as root check attributes with `lsattr /var/log/hawkey.log`. If you see immutable flag `i` remove it with `chattr -i /var/log/hawkey.log`.

Comment: @roaima and @Damir Thanks for the update. But not working. there isn't ```hawkey.log``` file. Only older files available. Is this file related to any service?

Comment: Are you running the command as root?

Comment: @roaima Yes. running the command as root

Answer (score 1):

Check `/Var/log` partition size, it might be full therefor dnf can't write new logs